# What should I use for an interior door threshold if the clearance is only 1/2”?

Tags: doors, carpet, hardwood, clearance, threshold

I just had hardwood floors installed in my office and I need to install a threshold to cover where the hallway carpet and hardwood join. The challenge is, the clearance is only 1/2” under the door (a little more toward the outer edges of the door.) It’s a metal door so trimming the door isn’t an option. I’d like something that looks professional, not a protective tape etc. What are my options? THANKS!

Comment: That's a "transition", not a threshold.

Comment: It's a bit odd that your flooring installer didn't deal with this. It's normally part of the job.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't cover the carpet in that scenario. You just use a termination molding with a vertical face against which carpet is tucked. Typically the top flange on these isn't more than 1/4" thick.

```
            ____________
          /    _________|_____________________
|||||||| |    ||
|||||||| |____||
```